# How do I shutdown a rails server without a console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a "`rails server`" in my Mac OS X terminal. Supposedly if I just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in that terminal, I can shut it down. But I accidentally closed the terminal and now I can't shut it down.

I started another test project and try "`rails server`" again, and I got

> Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)" error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Another pointer, you can and should use Apache / Nginx for development along side Passenger, stuff like that just don't happen there and it will output a similar environment to your production.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `killall -9 rails` to kill all running apps with "rails" in the name.

The app *should* have died when the window closed though I have seen Ruby and/or Rails apps stick. You can have the system tell you if any "ruby" or "rails" apps are running with one of these commands:

```
ps auxw | grep ruby
ps auxw | grep rails`
```

This is the output of the first one:

```
greg     14461   0.3  0.7  2483432  15000 s001  S+   10:10PM   1:03.43 /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby script/rails c
```

You can see the path to the running app which will help identify the job. The number in the second column is the process ID. `kill -9 14461` would kill it. Or, like above the `killall` command will do it by searching for apps with `rails` in the name.

Comment: Good scoop. I'd been using `ps aux | grep ruby` and then running `kill -9 <pid>`.  I think I'll adopt your syntax instead.

Comment: What if you're running multiple rails servers? How would you kill exactly one of them? I have 6 sites running off of one server, I can't kill all of them.